# Algorithm to position a circle within an area with Restricted Area Polygon and with certain distance of Target Polygons

Tags: algorithm, constraint-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I'm having difficulties coming up with an algorithm for the following problem.

I need to place a circle with radius R (give it latlon coordinates).

Goal:

- There are "Target Polygons", each with a "**min distance**" parameter.
  The distance from the center of the circle to the farthest point in the polygon must not be
  greater than "**min distance + R**"

Restrictions:

- The circle must **not overlap** with polygons ("Restricted Areas")

I've tried formulating it as a MILP problem or CSP problem, without success.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't create algorithms to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.